Azure DevOps Self-Hosted Linux Agent goes offline automatically after successfully getting configured
I've a ubuntu linux VM(Ubuntu) on Azure with version 20.04. I want to make it as self-hosted agent on Azure DeVOps. I logged in to the VM with Bastion and executed the follwing comamnds.

mkdir myagent && cd myagent
wget https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.214.1/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.214.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.214.1.tar.gz
./config.sh
- Accept the Team Explorer Everywhere license agreement now? - Typed Y and enter
- Enter server URL ---> https://dev.azure.com/yourorganization
- Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) > Clicked enter
- Enter personal access token, ---> Entered PAT token with full access.
- Enter Agent pool ---> enterd pool name
- Enter Agent name --> myBuildAgent_1
- Enter work folder > enter
Configured as Service by running follwoing commands.

sudo ./svc.sh install &
./runsvc.sh &



Now on Azure DevOps it's succesfully showing online.
Online status on ADO
But after some time it's going offline automatically but when i run ./runsvc.sh & again it's coming online, but again after some time I clsed the bastion session or after sometime it's going offline.
Offline Status on ADO
I want it to be up and running 24/7.
How to do this ????

Entering sudo ./svc.sh start solved my issue.

Thank you! FYI You also need to enter your agent's directory to run this.
